# Msql not compiled for 64 bit

Tags: mysql, windows, wampserver

Is it affects the mysql is not compiled for 64 bit make the server process high cpu load and late response for the user access your website?

Our server host 7 website and 2 of this is with large database and the other open and read thousands of textfile lines.

What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** Is it affects the mysql is not compiled for 64 bit make the server process high cpu load and late response for the user access your website?

**A:** No.

**Q:** What is the best solution for this?

**A:** Capacity planning. Figure out what is causing the slowness, identify the system bottlenecks, which resources are constrained, (network, i/o, cpu, memory, etc.)... if database queries taking a significant portion of the response time, identify the problematic SQL and take steps to improve performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Ill try to figure it out.

Comment: By the way i check the server status in advisor tab, the recommendation is to change mysql that compiled to 64 bit.

Comment: I am using using uniserver 11.what is the best host server?